# Assert arrays using Chai (or Should) in Javascript ES6 (using Babel)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, chai, babeljs

I'm trying to test an array such as:

```
let projects = [
    {  
        "id": "55a75be01fa2c7ff76a2ce7a",
        "title: "Only-Ben",
        "other_keys": "that can contain objects or arrays"
    },
    {
        "id": "55a75be01fa2c7ff76a2ce7d",
        "title: "Only-Thomas"
    },
    {
        "id": "55a75be01fa2c7ff76a2ce7c",
        "title: "Other-Project"
    }
];
```

The goal is to test that the array

- Contains an element which has a key `{title: 'Only Ben'}`
- Do not contain an element which has a key `{title: 'Only Thomas'}`

I'm currently using [chai.js](http://chaijs.com/) and [chai things](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-things) with this test:

```
projects.should.include.something.that.deep.have.property('title', 'Only Thomas');
```

This is my **error response**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'something' of undefined
```

Just to make things clearer, I've tried running the example given in Chai Things documentation:

```
[{ a: 'cat' }, { a: 'dog' }].should.include.something.that.deep.equals({ a: 'cat' })
```

And I still get a similar error response:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'something' of undefined
```

It seems to me that the issue might be caused by the use of [Babel](https://babeljs.io). My Node project heavily uses ES6 syntax, that's the reason why I'm using Babel. In order to run mocha tests with babel I'm using a babel-hook:

```
(in package.json)
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require babelhook --reporter spec",
    }
}
```

**How can I fix this undefined error when asserting arrays?**

==EDIT==

I've made 2 tests (with and without babel) to confirm that Babel is the issue in this scenario. Here they are:

**1. Test without babel**

```
var chai = require("chai");
chai.should();
chai.use(require('chai-things'));

describe('Array', function() {
   it('Test array', function(cb){
       [{ a: 'cat' }, { a: 'dog' }].should.include.something.that.deep.equals({ a: 'cat' })
        cb();
   });

});
```

Result: **Test pass**

**2. Test with babel**

```
import chai from 'chai';
let should = chai.should;
let expect = chai.expect;
import chai_things from 'chai-things';
chai.use(chai_things);

describe('Array', function() {
   it('Test array', function(cb){
       [{ a: 'cat' }, { a: 'dog' }].should.include.something.that.deep.equals({ a: 'cat' })
        cb();
   });
});
```

Result: **Error**: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'something' of undefined`

Comment: Are you saying that you don't get the error without babel?

Comment: How did you import that `things` plugin for chai?

Comment: @Bergi : I've edited the question with 2 scenarios (with and without babel). The issue comes from Babel (confirmed) and you can see in the edit how I include `chai-things`

Comment: Not sure whether that makes a difference, but *shouldn't* you invoke `chai.should` instead of storing it in a variable?

Comment: @Bergi unfortunately it doesn't makes any difference

Comment: Have you tried using a mocha.opts file for your babel compilation ?

Answer (score 2):

The second version (with Babel) does not work because your test forgets to call `chai.should()`. In my testing, once that method call is added, everything works as expected (the test passes).

It also seems that Bergi was correct in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512518/assert-arrays-using-chai-or-should-in-javascript-es6-using-babel#comment50988714_31512518) comment.

If this does not work for you, it seems that in order to help you, we would need more information. It might help to provide the source code of the `babelhook` `--compilers` option you are using. (The standard way of referencing Babel from Mocha's compiler option is `mocha --compilers js:babel/register`.)

Here is my test code:

```
import chai from 'chai';
chai.should();
import chaiThings from "chai-things";
chai.use(chaiThings);

describe('Array', function() {
   it('Test array', function(cb){
       [{ a: 'cat' }, { a: 'dog' }].should.include.something.that.deep.equals({ a: 'cat' })
        cb();
   });
});
```